# Find matrix rows (by column) greater than values specified in a matrix or vector

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrices:

```
m = matrix(c(1:12), nrow=4)
p = matrix(c(2,7,11), nrow=1)
```

Per each column of `m` and `p`, I want to find the values in the columns of `m` which are less than the values in columns of `p`

```
p = 1 6 11 

m = 1 5 9
    2 6 10
    3 7 11
    4 8 12
```

So that I can get something like this:

```
ans = m[,] > p[,]

ans = 
    F F F
    T F F
    T T F
    T T T
```

(or something similar)

I have tried `m[,] > p[,]`  and also set `p` to be a vector, but neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lapply(1:length(p), function(x) m[p[x] > m[,x],x])
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m > p[rep(1, 4,),]
```

Replicates row 1 of p 4 times so that they are now the same size and the > comparison can be done.

It can be made more general by using:

```
m > p[rep(1, nrow(m),),]
```

That way, p single row is replicated as many times as m rows.

Answer (score 1):

`mapply(function(x,y) x > max(y), as.data.frame(m), as.data.frame(p))`

Answer (score 0):

you can also `apply` the equality test to each row of `m`

```
> t(apply(m, 1, function(x) x > p))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
>
```

I get your answer if I use your second `p`

```
p <- c(1, 6, 11)

> t(apply(m, 1, function(x) x > p))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
>
```